# Why .contains only returns true if it is an exact match in the app, but works fine in developer console?

Tags: contains

In the developer console this works fine:

```
String op1 = '12345';
String op2 = '1234';
Boolean tmpResult = true;

system.debug('op1: '+op1+', op2: ' +op2+', tmpResult: ' +tmpResult );
tmpResult = op1.contains(op2) ? true : false;
system.debug('op1: '+op1+', op2: ' +op2+', tmpResult: ' +tmpResult );

*USER_DEBUG [14]|DEBUG|op1: 12345, op2: 1234, tmpResult: true*
*USER_DEBUG [16]|DEBUG|op1: 12345, op2: 1234, tmpResult: true*
```

However, in the Salesforce debug log:

```
18:15:15.0 (329852706)|USER_DEBUG|[926]|DEBUG|op1: “12345”, op2: “1234”, tmpResult: true
18:15:15.0 (329862345)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[927]
18:15:15.0 (329878427)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[927]|Bytes:5
18:15:15.0 (329886433)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[927]|tmpResult|false
18:15:15.0 (329892809)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[928]
18:15:15.0 (329901057)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[928]|Bytes:5
18:15:15.0 (329912132)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[928]|Bytes:43
18:15:15.0 (329920824)|USER_DEBUG|[928]|DEBUG|op1: “12345”, op2: “1234”, tmpResult: false
18:15:15.0 (329932369)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[957]
18:15:15.0 (329934421)|STATEMENT_EXECUTE|[958]
18:15:15.0 (329937300)|HEAP_ALLOCATE|[958]|Bytes:5
18:15:15.0 (329944944)|VARIABLE_ASSIGNMENT|[958]|result|false
```

After the line 927 `tmpResult = op1.contains(op2) ? true : false;`, it turns false. The only clue I have is that it returns true if the value is exact same.

I tried `tmpResult = op2.contains(op1) ? true : false;`, the result is same - only true when it is exact value.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading the API version of the apex class to most recent one?

Comment: @Raul The API version of the Apex class is 47.0, and I can't upgrade it until tomorrow.

Comment: By the way, `tmpResult = op2.contains(op1) ? true : false;` is the same as just `tmpResult = op2.contains(op1)`. A Boolean value is already a Boolean value, which is what `.contains` returns.

Comment: @sfdcfox I think you are right about the double quote, I added ```op1 = op1.replaceAll('"', '');
op2 = op2.replaceAll('"', '');```, but it only works for developer console. In the debug log, system debug still shows the quotes and it still return false

Comment: @sfdcfox I found out the double quote on my keyboard is different than the one generated in salesforce... copy and pasted that opening and closing double quote works. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears from your debug statements and the code you have, that the inputs were actually surrounded by quotes: `“12345”` and `“1234”`, rather than `12345` and `1234`. In this case, neither string will return `.contains` because of the quotes.

```
      / Mismatch at 5.
 “12345” 
 “1234”
      \ Mismatch at ”.
```

Thus, I suspect the problem is not in your code, but in your data. You'll want to check your inputs carefully.